# Error importing 'pandas' in python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7

I am importing pandas on Python 2.7.12 and on Jupyter, and I had never had this issue.

> ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. 
>   If you want to import pandas from the source directory, 
>   you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

[image: e]

Comment: I worked with 'pandas' for a few months without problems and now I am not pretty sure what is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried running the suggested command?

Comment: Yes, I tried to running the suggested command but it returns another error and then i realized that the 'pandas folder' doesn't have any 'setup.py'.

Comment: How about deleting ~/anaconda2 and reinstalling the latest version? (make sure you don't have any stray notebooks in there)

Comment: I tried deleting and reinstalling my anaconda2 folder twice, and i have the same problem, i suppose that my problem is about an update of anaconda, i am not sure about that.